# In Grails, how do I get the discriminator value?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, discriminator

I have a class like this:

```
class Apple extends Fruit {
    static mapping = {
        discriminator "AppleType"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get this discriminator value in the controller/view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the mapping of your domain class with the [Mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/Mapping.html) class. Example:

```
def mapping = GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Apple)
println mapping.discriminator
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Sergio's answer, the `GrailsDomainBinder`, as of 2.3, no longer has the `getMapping()` method as static. You must instead instantiate a `GrailsDomainBinder`.

```
def mapping = new GrailsDomainBinder().getMapping(Apple)
println mapping.discriminator
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used this hack in the past.  Create a derived property on the base class that queries the discriminator column.

```
static mapping = {
    fruitType formula: "class"  // discriminator column defaults to 'class'
}

String fruitType
```

This adds a fruitType property that gets set every time the class is pulled from the database.

**The property will be null until it is fetched from the db.**

If you change your discriminator column, just change the formula accordingly.

```
static mapping = {
    discriminator column: "custom_column_name"
    fruitType formula: "custom_column_name"
}

String fruitType
```